# How to use Multiple/Wildcard hosttype in Azure Application Gateway for various API endpoints

Tags: azure, api, terraform, azure-application-gateway

I have configured Azure application gateway for a Front End (FE) Web App and an API Web App (Backend)
Both the app services are private endpoint enabled and VNET integrated
The FE web app is working fine

But the API app or the backend App is being called by Mulesoft which is sitting in AWS
This API or BE app has multiple APIs, so one API calling another API

Right now in the Listener Type in App Gateway , it is set to "Multi site" with Host Type --> Single and the URL is "my-api-dev.contoso.com".

This is the friendly URL of my BE web app which is set as Custom Domain in my Web App

So in order to achieve my use case as mentioned above, what do i need to do in the App Gateway listener for this API Backend App ?

Should i choose Hosttype "Multiple/Wildcard" and then what do i specify in there?

From Mulesoft the format of the APIs that are being called are :

"my-api-dev.contoso.com//token",

"my-api-dev.contoso.com/api/shippingnotice",

so on and so forth.

I am using Terraform to configure my App Gateway

So in Terraform, where do i make the change ?

Is it in this part of the code where i am specifying "url_path_map" ? here?

```
 url_path_map = {
      api = {
            name                               = "api-path"
            default_backend_address_pool_name  = "api-pool"
            default_backend_http_settings_name = "api-http"
            path_rules = [
              {
                name                       = "api-path-rule"
                paths                      = ["/api/*"]
                backend_address_pool_name  = "api-pool"
                backend_http_settings_name = "api-http"
                firewall_policy_id         = azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy.web_application_firewall_policy.id
              }
            ]
          }
}
```

Looking forward to some help on this

Answer (score 0):

In **url_path_map**  , you can define `path rules` one after the other with **`path_rule`** for the backend with proper api and http settings.

---

> The url_path_map is used to specify Path patterns to back-end server
> pool mappings.

---

Please check below code .

*example:*

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "kavyavnet"
  location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "integrationsubnet" {
  name                 = "integrationsubnet"
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  delegation {
    name = "delegation"
    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "endpointsubnet" {
  name                 = "endpointsubnet"
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                = "kaaappserviceplan"
  location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  os_type             = "Windows"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "frontwebapp" {
  name                = "myfrntendappnme"
location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id

  site_config {}
  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER": "168.63.129.16",
    "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL": "1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "vnetintegrationconnection" {
  app_service_id  = azurerm_windows_web_app.frontwebapp.id
  subnet_id       = azurerm_subnet.integrationsubnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "backwebapp" {
  name                = "backendappnm"
 location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id

  site_config {}
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "dnsprivatezone" {
  name                = "privatelink.azurewebsites.net"
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "dnszonelink" {
  name = "dnszonelink"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.dnsprivatezone.name
  virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "privateendpoint" {
  name                = "backwebappprivateendpoint"
  location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.endpointsubnet.id

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name = "privatednszonegroup"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.dnsprivatezone.id]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name = "privateendpointconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_windows_web_app.backwebapp.id
    subresource_names = ["sites"]
    is_manual_connection = false
  }
}


resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
  name                = "acceptanceTestPublicIp1"
  location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"


  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "myNSG" {
  name                = "kavya-nsg"
   location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name


    security_rule {
    name                       = "Allow_Port_65200_to_65535"
    priority                   = 300
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "65200-65535"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  
}
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "myNSGAssociation" 
{
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.integrationsubnet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.myNSG.id
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "main" {
  name                = "myAppGateway"
   location            =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
   name     = "Standard_v2"
   tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "my-gateway-ip-configuration"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.integrationsubnet.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = var.frontend_port_name
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = var.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pip.id
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = var.backend_address_pool_name
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = var.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 60
  }

   url_path_map  {
      name                               = "myurl-path-map"
      default_backend_address_pool_name  = var.backend_address_pool_name 
      default_backend_http_settings_name = var.http_setting_name

      #path rule 1
      path_rule {
        
          name                       = "api-token-rule"
          paths                      = ["/app1/*"]
          backend_address_pool_name  = var.backend_address_pool_name
          backend_http_settings_name = var.http_setting_name
        }
      #path rule 2
       path_rule {
          name                       = "api-shippingnotice-rule"
          paths                      = ["/api2/*"]
          backend_address_pool_name  = var.backend_address_pool_name
          backend_http_settings_name = var.http_setting_name
        }
      }
  
  http_listener {
    name                           = var.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = var.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = var.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = var.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = var.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = var.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = var.http_setting_name
    priority                   = 1
  }
}
```

[image]

> **Note :** ***For the above configuration, make sure to allow incoming Internet traffic on TCP ports 65503-65534 for the Application Gateway
> v1 SKU  and TCP ports 65200-65535 for the v2 SKU***

[image]

Please also check **Reference:**  [GitHub - kumarvna/terraform-azurerm-application-gateway: Terraform module to create Azure Application gateway](https://github.com/kumarvna/terraform-azurerm-application-gateway)